# RxAndroidBle - Can I perform combine a variable number of writes to a characteristic using a single command?

Tags: android, rx-android, rxandroidble

I have an array containing multiple pieces of data that need to be written to the same characteristic, but I want to be notified when the entire process is finished.

I can accomplish the writes by looping over my array as follows:

```
byte[][] dataArray = getDataArray();
for (byte[] values: dataArray) {
    rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, values)
        .subscribe(bytes -> {
            // here I am notified after each individual write
        }, throwable -> {
            // handle error per write
        });
}
```

However, this method is slow and I am unable to detect when the entire write process has been finished. Is there a way to combine the writes together somehow so that I can listen for the completion of the entire write transaction?

I can't use `Observable.merge` because `dataArray` may have a variable size and more than 9 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to combine the writes together somehow so that I can listen for the completion of the entire write transaction?

Yes, there is a way. You may transform the `byte[][]` into an `Observable<byte[]>` which emissions will get processed in a `.flatMap()`. Then you just need to wait for the completion of the chain. i.e.:

```
Observable.from(Arrays.asList(getDataArray()))
    .flatMap(values -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, values))
    .ignoreElements() // transform to a `Completable` as you are interested only in the completion
    .subscribe(
        () -> { /* all values have been successfully written */ },
        throwable -> { /* an error happened during one of the writes */ }
    );
```